# Connect to custom SQL Database

Tags: google-app-maker

I have two domains, one is production and the other one is test. I have set up GCP on the production domain and that is where the SQL databases reside. I have two instances, one is used for prod and the other is for testing. I am trying to connect the test domain to a custom cloud sql database that resides on the production domain, inside the testing instance, but I am getting the following error:

[image]

Now, before you might assume that it is a permission error; IT IS NOT, or at least that's what I believe. This was working fine until last week. I have doubled checked that the permissions are correct and here is the screenshot of the permission inside IAM & Admin:

[image]

I have checked and followed [**the documentation**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17-jTVh3LUVSwKJSssgcMbR8MMwZIWqN2nzzbAFGo1L0/edit#heading=h.puk8541061lx) that James from AppMaker university shared but that is not what it's happening now. It's just NOT working.

Now, I suspect this is a bug or a recent change but I see no communication whatsoever regarding this behavior. I see no sense in creating another GCP account and another billing account in the test domain, when I already have a GCP account with an instance that I want to use. Would it be possible to continue doing this or the appmaker team decided to remove this ability?

Comment: Can you connect to the instance as Custom SQL on your prod App Maker instance ('App Settings -> Database -> Switch to a custom database')?

Comment: @PavelShkleinik Hi Pavel, thanks for your interest. I am able to do as you mention. The only problem is, in other words, when I try to connect to a custom SQL database of an external domain; but that was working pretty neat until last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Maker application developer (a person which creates or updates the deployment in particular) should have "Cloud SQL Client" permission on the Cloud Project with Cloud SQL DB.

Comment: Vasyl, YOU ARE THE MAN!!! Boy I admire your knowledge! This was the whole problem.. no idea where you found that info but huge thanks man! Weird thing is that this was not needed before.